# JSON contains array of nulls with three objects - expected only three objects

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using a standalone Google Apps Script and a Google Spreadsheet. I have this script which returns as JSON an array of nulls and three objects, but I expected only to get three objects. Its a search, and when a zipcode is searched, the script is to return any matches. The thing is, it returns the matches successfully, but it also returns a null for each row that was not a match, in the order the rows appear on the [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1280aUAvFoUDP2rtpCFS2JYR7TuQNYcd5gm8QudukiGc/edit?usp=sharing). To make it work, the `function testDoGetWithZipcode()` should be run.

I don't know if I'm supposed to get those nulls, if they matter, or how I can fix it. It doesn't seem to go with anything I've learned about JSON so far but before even asking this I did an hour and a half Lynda.com course on Javascript and JSON and read the JSON.org website and read the documentation on Mozilla about JSON. I've adjusted variables in all of the functions because at first I thought it was in the `function formatOrganization()` but now I'm completely stumped.

```
s = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1280aUAvFoUDP2rtpCFS2JYR7TuQNYcd5gm8QudukiGc");
var sheet = s.getSheetByName("RAP - Data");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var headings = data[0];

function zipcodeQuery(zipcode) {
 zipcodeArray = [];
 for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
  if (zipcode === data[i][4].toString()){
    zipcodeArray.push(data[i]);
  }
 }
  return zipcodeArray
}

function formatOrganization(rowData){
 var organization = {}
 for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++){
   Logger.log('Headings: ' + headings[i]);
   organization[headings[i].toString()] = rowData[i];
 }
 return  organization
}

function executeZipcodeQuery(request) {

     zipcodes = request.parameters.zipcode;

      // The object to be returned as JSON
  response = {
        organizations : []
      }

      // Fill the organzations dictionary with requested organizations
      for (var i = 0; i < zipcodes.length; i++) { 
        sheetData = zipcodeQuery(zipcodes[i]);
        if(sheetData !== undefined) {
          for (var orgIndex = 0; orgIndex < sheetData.length; orgIndex++) { 
            var org = formatOrganization(sheetData[orgIndex]);
            if(org !== undefined) {
               Logger.log('Org object: ' + org);
               if(typeof org === 'object') {
                  //FIXME
                 var orgId = parseInt(org.Id);
                 Logger.log('Org Id: ' + orgId);
                 response.organizations[orgId] = org
                 //response.organizations.push({orgId : org});
               }
            }
          }  
        }
      }
      if (response.organizations.length > 0)
      {
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response.organizations));
      } 
      else 
      {
        return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid Request. zipcode(s) not found.');
      } 
}

function testDoGetWithZipcode() {
  var testRequest = {"parameter":{"zipcode":"19132"},"contextPath":"","contentLength":-1,"queryString":"zipcode=19132","parameters":{"zipcode":["19132"]}};

  var textResult = doGet(testRequest);
  textResult.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

  Logger.log('Mime Type: ' + textResult.getMimeType());
  Logger.log('Result content: ' + textResult.getContent());
}
```

The return I get is this (abridged because there's over a 180 rows in the spreadsheet and they're all represented in the return by either null or an object):

```
[
   null,
   ....
   null,
   {
      "Id":61,
      "Category":"Day / Drop in Centers",
      "Organization Name":"Philadelphia Recovery Community Center (PRCC)",
      "Address":"1701 W Lehigh Ave, Philadelphia, PA 19132",
      "Zip Code":19132,
      "Days":"Mon, Tues, Thurs, Fri: 12-8pm, Wed: 9-5pm, Sat: 9-1pm",
      "Time: Open":"",
      "Time: Close":"",
      "People Served":"Women, Men, Families",
      "Description":"Case management, outpatient treatment, youth programs, training programs",
      "Phone Number":"215-223-7700"
   },
....
   null,
   {
      "Id":81,
      "Category":"Emergency Shelter",
      "Organization Name":"Station House",
      "Address":"2601 N Broad St, Philadelphia, PA 19132",
      "Zip Code":19132,
      "Days":"",
      "Time: Open":"",
      "Time: Close":"",
      "People Served":"Men",
      "Description":"After hours reception for single men\n 2601 N. Broad Street\n After 4 pm",
      "Phone Number":"215-225-9230"
   },
   null,
...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original object is this:

```
response = {
    organizations : []
  }
```

The value of the key/value pair for `organizations` is an array.  But you are using notation as if `organizations` was an object.

```
response.organizations[orgId] = org
```

You could push a value into the array with:

```
response.organizations.push(org);
```

I'd probably try something like this:

```
var tempObject = {}; //Reset every time
tempObject[orgId] = org;
response.organizations.push(tempObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, the `response.organizations.push(org)` worked great. I tried that one before but I kept the `= org` when I was experimenting and that did not work. Thanks for the help!